# Write the same string or variable to multiple cells in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to simplifie this code in VBA.  I have multiple cells in a worksheet that will change based on the change of a combobox.  How can I make this more efficient?

```
'upon change, Units data to input worksheet
Public Sub cboUnits_Change()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("b4") = Worksheets("calculator").cboUnits.ListIndex
    Worksheets("Input").Range("c4") = Worksheets("calculator").cboUnits.Value
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        If .cboUnits.ListIndex = 2 Then
            .Range("aw37", "aw38") = "ft/s"
            .Range("x31", "x32") = "ft/s"
            .Range("AF31") = "ft/s"
            
        Else
            .Range("aw37", "AW38") = "m/s"
            .Range("x31", "x32") = "m/s"
            .Range("AF31") = "m/s"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Something like `.Range("E1,F2") = "test"` ?

Comment: If your code works fine but you're just looking to make it more efficient, it's better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```vb
'upon change, Units data to input worksheet
Public Sub cboUnits_Change()
    Worksheets("Input").Range("b4") = Worksheets("calculator").cboUnits.ListIndex
    Worksheets("Input").Range("c4") = Worksheets("calculator").cboUnits.Value
    
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        .range("AW37:AW38,X31:X32,AF31").value = IIf(.cboUnits.ListIndex = 2,"ft/s","m/s")
    End With
End Sub
```